# TypoScript: Reading content from a file within a CONTENT object

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Please don't be afraid of the lenght of this question - **I think the solution will be quite simple...**

**Synopsis:**

I have created a `CONTENT` object in TypoScript to read the content of a database. One of the resulting fields is the filename of a textfile **but I cannot find out how to render the content of the filename within the CONTENT object.**

I found out that I could read the content of a given file with something like:

```
30 = FILE
30.file = <filepath>/<filename>
```

But in my going I have not found out:

a) How to use the result of a CONTENT field as variable for the `<filepath>/<filename>`

b) How to suppress the FILE-OBJECT under certain circumstances, as it seems not to react to `.if`-conditions.

**EXAMPLE: My actual Problem**

I want to read all videofiles which have been created as an "Text & Media" content element in the backend and show the URLs to those files with my typoscript in the frontend. My script works fine for locally stored videos because I could read the filepath of those videos from the database. But in case the user created a Youtube video in the backend I find no way to read the URL of that video because all I get is a filepath to a textfile which then contains the URL (or to be exact the unique ID of the URL). So where I fail is to extract this ID from the file...

**Current TypoScript:**

```
obj.content_video = CONTENT
obj.content_video {

table = tt_content
select {
    pidInList = this
    selectFields = identifier,mime_type
    leftjoin = `sys_file_reference` ON tt_content.uid = sys_file_reference.uid_foreign LEFT JOIN `sys_file` ON sys_file.uid = sys_file_reference.uid_local
    where =  tt_content.CType = 'textmedia' AND tt_content.colPos = 1 AND tt_content.deleted=0 AND sys_file_reference.deleted=0
    orderBy = tt_content.uid
}

renderObj = COA
renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = identifier
    10.wrap = <div>MP4-Video: href="/fileadmin|"</div><br>
    10.if {
        value = video/mp4
        equals.field = mime_type
    }

    20 = TEXT
    20.field = identifier
    20.wrap = <div>Youtube-Video: href="/fileadmin|"</div><br>
    20.if {
        value = video/youtube
        equals.field = mime_type
    }
}
}
```

**Current Result:**

As I uploaded in the backend two locally stored videos and one Youtube video that results in:

> MP4-Video: href="/fileadmin/myvideos/first_video.mp4"
>
> MP4-Video: href="/fileadmin/myvideos/second_video.mp4"
>
> Youtube-Video: href="/fileadmin/user_upload/some_youtube_file.youtube"

**Wanted result:**

> MP4-Video: href="/fileadmin/myvideos/first_video.mp4"
>
> MP4-Video: href="/fileadmin/myvideos/second_video.mp4"
>
> Youtube-Video: href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**VIDEO-ID**"

where the VIDEO-ID is the content of the file */fileadmin/user_upload/some_youtube_file.youtube* - which is the content of the field 'identifier' in case of Youtube files.

**How do I need to change the above code to get the wanted result?**

Comment: Maybe you could combine the FILES cObject with the FILE object. Like it is done here with the IMAGE object https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I have tried this before but unfortunally I did not come to a solution with it. Especially I did not understand how to use my 'identifier' field (or in ID which I might also request) that I got from my original CONTENT request in the FILES request...